# glassfish v3 multiple domain hosting

Tags: glassfish, hosting, dns, glassfish-3, virtualhost

I have a website running with glassfish and I want to now use the same server to host another domain on a completely new domain name. What are the steps involved in configuring glassfish to support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new virtual server and assign the new domain name to it. You can use the admin console to achieve this:

*Configuration --> Virtual Servers --> new*

Assign a name to the new virtual server (Field: Id) and set your domain name (Field: Hosts). Choose one or more http-listeners and restart your server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually this is achieved by adding a new Virtual server in GlassFish admin console panel.
You can easily [Run Multiple Custom Domains on GlassFish Server](http://blog.jelastic.com/2013/08/19/running-multiple-custom-domains-on-glassfish-server/) with Jelastic.

This instruction shows you how to manage this with every needed detail provided.